# ComboBox DataContex not updated property which is placed inside the ContentControl (UWP)?

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have used `ComboBox` in `ContentTemplate` of `ContentControl`. Initially, I bind the `DataContext` (`Profession1`) with content property of `ContentControl` in code behind.

Then I am changing value of `ComboBox` in runtime. After that, while changing the `DataContext` of `ContentControl` as `Profession2` in runtime. In this case, `ComboBox` `DataContext` is not changed, also previous `DataContext` of  `SelectedItem` value set as null.

I think this is an issue in MSControl. Please any suggest your idea to resolve this issue.

Please refer the below code:

View:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <local:MainPageViewModel x:Key="datacontent"></local:MainPageViewModel>
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
          Margin="10">
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" >
            <ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Professions}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Profession, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                                     
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></ComboBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentControl.ContentTemplate>
        </ContentControl>
         <Button Click="Button_Click_2" Content="Change DataContext" Width="100" Height="50"></Button>
     </Grid>
</Page>
```

Model & ViewModel:

```
  public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {            
            Profession1 = new Person();
            Profession2 = new Person();                      
          private Person profession1;

        public Person Profession1
        {
            get { return profession1; }
            set { this.profession1 = value; }
        }

        private Person profession2;

        public Person Profession2
        {
            get { return profession2; }
            set { this.profession2 = value; }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Person()
        {
            _professions = new List<string>();
            _professions.Add("Lawyer");
            _professions.Add("Politician");
            _professions.Add("Other");         
        }

        private string _profession;
        public string Profession
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_profession))
                {
                    // _profession = _professions.LastOrDefault();
                }
                return _profession;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_profession != value)
                {
                    _profession = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Profession");
                }
            }
        }      

        private List<string> _professions;

        public List<string> Professions
        {
            get
            {
                return _professions;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Code Behind:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        Binding binding;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            var datacontent = (this.Resources["datacontent"] as MainPageViewModel);
            this.UpdateBinding1(this.contentControl, datacontent);
        }         

        public void UpdateBinding1(FrameworkElement contentcontrol, object datacontext)
        {
            binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Profession1");
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            binding.Source = datacontext;  // view model
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentcontrol, ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
        }

        public void UpdateBinding(FrameworkElement contentcontrol, object datacontext)
        {
            binding = new Binding();
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Profession2");
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
            binding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
            binding.Source = datacontext;  // view model
            BindingOperations.SetBinding(contentcontrol, ContentControl.ContentProperty, binding);
        }

       private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var datacontext = (this.Resources["datacontent"] as MainPageViewModel);
            this.UpdateBinding(this.contentControl,datacontext);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After that, while changing the DataContext of ContentControl as Profession2 in runtime.

The binding path do updated from `Profession1` to `Profession2`. And the `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox` is updated. But since you defined  `Profession1` and `Profession2` to the same values so it looks like the binding source doesn't updated. Please set them to different values to check the result. For example, update your `MainViewModel` as follows:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    List<string> Profession1list=new List<string>() { "Lawyer", "Politician", "Other" };
    List<string> Profession2list = new List<string>() { "Lawyer2", "Politician2", "Other2" };
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Profession1 = new Person(Profession1list);
        Profession2 = new Person(Profession2list);
    }
      private Person profession1;

    public Person Profession1
    {
        get { return profession1; }
        set { this.profession1 = value; }
    }

    private Person profession2;

    public Person Profession2
    {
        get { return profession2; }
        set { this.profession2 = value; }
    }

   ...

}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person(List<string> Professionlist)
    {
        _professions = new List<string>();
        foreach(string item in Professionlist)
        {
            _professions.Add(item);
        }

        //_professions.Add("Lawyer");
        //_professions.Add("Politician");
        //_professions.Add("Other");
    }     

    private List<string> _professions;

    public List<string> Professions
    {
        get
        {
            return _professions;
        }
    }
  ...

}
```

> In this case, ComboBox DataContext is not changed, also previous DataContext of  SelectedItem value set as null.

Since the `ItemsSource` of `ComboBox` is updated by re-binding, so the `SelectedItem` cleared.

My testing environment is OS build 15063. More details please reference [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart). If you detail the scenarios you are using for this feature, we may provide a better practice for that.  For example, to avoid updating the binding path to meet the requirements but by other ways.

Comment: HI Sunteen, Thanks for your update. I have raised one more question related with this query https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112424/comboboxprevious-datacontext-selecteditem-property-set-as-null-value-in-uwp                                   Please share your idea on this.