# ComboBox(Previous DataContext) SelectedItem property set as null value in UWP?

Tags: c#, combobox, uwp

Initially, `ComboBox` `DataContext` is set with `Profession1` and `SelectedValue` as Politician. At Runtime, i changed the `Datacontext` to `Profession2`. Doing this is changing the `Profession1` to null.

#### Please refer the below code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:MainPageViewModel x:Key="datacontent"></local:MainPageViewModel>
</Page.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Professions,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Profession, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"                              
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

#### Code Behind:

```
var datacontent = (this.Resources["datacontent"] as MainPageViewModel);
this.comboBox.DataContext = datacontent.Profession1;
```

#### Model:

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{       
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        Profession1 = new Person();        
        Profession2 = new Person();
    }
    private Person profession1;

    public Person Profession1
    {
        get { return profession1; }
        set { this.profession1 = value; }
    }

    private Person profession2;

    public Person Profession2
    {
        get { return profession2; }
        set { this.profession2 = value; }
    }
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{       
    public Person()
    {
        _professions = new List<string>();
        _professions.Add("Lawyer");
        _professions.Add("Politician");
        _professions.Add("Other");
    }

    private string _profession;
    public string Profession
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_profession))
            {
                // _profession = _professions.LastOrDefault();
            }
            return _profession;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_profession != value)
            {
                _profession = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Profession");
            }
        }
    }      

    private List<string> _professions;

    public List<string> Professions
    {
        get
        {
            return _professions;
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the below code, to check the previous datacontext (Profession1->Professon) value .

**Code**

```
((this.Resources["datacontent"] as MainPageViewModel).Profession1 as Person).Profession
```

Output is : null.
Expected value : Politician

Please someone suggest on this.

Answer (score 1):

> `((this.Resources["datacontent"] as MainPageViewModel).Profession1 as Person).Profession`
>
> Output is : null. Expected value : Politician
>   Please someone suggest on this.

The problem is that when you modify the DataContext of `combobox`, the DataContext  is set null first and then turns to `Profession2`. So the `Profession` property of `Profession1` will be set null. For your requirement, you could set the judgment condition to solve this issue.

```
public string Profession
{
    get
    {

        return _profession;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_profession != value && value != null)
        {
            _profession = value;
            OnPropertyChange();
        }
    }
}
```